# cannot add PPA for claws-mail

Tags: 19.04, email, launchpad, claws

i am trying to install claws-mail on ubuntu 19.04. while running this command i get the below error. could anyone suggest on why am i getting this? what should be done to resolve this?

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/claws-mail
[sudo] password for <user>: 

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/claws-mail
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                                 
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                                              
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                         
Hit:6 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                                                                                      
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/claws-mail/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:7 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/terminix/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/claws-mail/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/claws-mail/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

trying to follow these commands to install.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/claws-mail
sudo apt update
sudo apt install claws-mail
```

Comment: That PPA does not support Disco if you are getting the 404.  See the duplicate that this has been marked as for more details.

Comment: if not, how can i install the claws-mail for ubuntu 19.04? because 404 error syas the claws-mail package is not found which i am adding as a fresh `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/claws-mail/ubuntu disco Release`.

Comment: claws-mail *is* in the repositories for 19.04 though.  What happens when you remove the PPA and try and install claws-mail?

Comment: i removed from the software-updater list and tried, still the same issue. So i did installed through the Ubuntu-Software tool.